# Converting to the same timezone in php

Tags: php, mysql, timezone

Strangeness. It's not an edge case. Rather, let's say my server stores it's date/time in America/Toronto. I then run the it through time conversion logic incase, say, you're on the west coast. Here's the code I got:

```
$timestamp = '2012-07-25 16:30:00';
$to = 'America/Toronto';
$from = 'America/Toronto';

// system timezone
$system = (new DateTimeZone($from));

// desired conversion timezone
$desired = (new DateTimeZone($to));

// timestamp DateTime object
$resource = (new DateTime($timestamp, $system));

// offset
$offset = $desired->getOffset($resource);
print($offset);
```

The offset that is getting printed at this point is -14440 (4 hours). I don't imagine the system or database timezones are coming in here (both of which are set to America/Toronto). Any light would be appreciated on this. Confusing :(

Answer (score 3):

[`DateTimeZone::getOffset()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.getoffset.php) returns the offset in seconds from GMT (-14440 = 4 hours for America/Toronto).

**Edit:**

Apologies for my initial confusion with [`DateTime::getOffset()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.getoffset.php)!

Anyway, to address the title of your question, use [`DateTime::setTimeZone()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php) to convert between timezones.

Comment: right. I just looked at the [`DateTimeZone::getOffset`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.getoffset.php) which does have required parameter, that's why I confused that... :-S

Comment: @zerkms you're right actually - I was misreading the code in the question, will edit again.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you're looking for, the offset between the 2 timezones.

```
// system timezone
$system = (new DateTimeZone($from));

// desired conversion timezone
$desired = (new DateTimeZone($to));

// timestamp DateTime object
$resource = (new DateTime($timestamp, $system));
$desiredDateTime = (new DateTime($timestamp, $desired));

// offset
$offset = $desired->getOffset($desiredDateTime) - $system->getOffset($resource);
print($offset);
```

Comment: exactly what i needed, calculating the real offset between the two, i found it confusing how getOffset worked.